# VB Tab control in draw.mode

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I am trying to make the tabs show horizontally on the right side of my form.  I can't use tabcontrol from tool box because of how the text displays.
I am using a code that I found to help me. But after exhausting all of my resources I can't seem to get the code to point to the tabPages collection. I have entries in there but the tabs show up blank.

```
 Public Sub New()
    tabControl1 = New TabControl()
    Dim tabPage1 As New TabPage()

    ' Sets the tabs to be drawn by the parent window Form1. 
    ' OwnerDrawFixed allows access to DrawItem. 
    tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed

    tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabPage1)
    tabControl1.Location = New Point(25, 25)
    tabControl1.Size = New Size(250, 250)

    tabPage1.TabIndex = 0

    myTabRect = tabControl1.GetTabRect(0)

    ClientSize = New Size(300, 300)
    Controls.Add(tabControl1)

    AddHandler tabControl1.DrawItem, AddressOf OnDrawItem
End Sub!
```

[tab Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCHQC.jpg)

Comment: There's something wrong with your OnDrawItem method.  You didn't post it so surely you forgot the code to actually draw the tabs.

Comment: I am working with the orig code from  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.drawmode%28v=vs.71%29.aspx, you are right and I'm going to see if I can get that to work to better understand it. I have never used the draw.mode so I was totally confused about some of the things on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up compiling this code from different sources to get this working,

```
    Private Sub TabControl1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.DrawItem
    Dim g As Graphics
    Dim sText As String

    Dim iX As Integer
    Dim iY As Integer
    Dim sizeText As SizeF
    Dim ctlTab As TabControl

    Dim r As New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + 2, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height - 2)

    ctlTab = CType(sender, TabControl)

    g = e.Graphics

    sText = ctlTab.TabPages(e.Index).Text
    sizeText = g.MeasureString(sText, ctlTab.Font)

    iX = e.Bounds.Left + 6
    iY = e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height - sizeText.Height) / 2

    g.DrawString(sText, ctlTab.Font, Brushes.Black, iX, iY)
End Sub
```

The text doesn't show up in the RAD but it does when I debug/run it.

Many thanks to LUC001 @ http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/125792-how-to-make-vertical-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `.Alignment` property of the TabControl to `Left` to use horizontal tabs.

If you don't like that, try a FlowLayoutPanel with a separate TabControl for each tab, e.g.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim flp As New FlowLayoutPanel
    flp.Dock = DockStyle.Left
    flp.AutoSize = True
    flp.AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly

    Me.Controls.Add(flp)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
      Dim tbc As New TabControl
      Dim tbp As New TabPage("Tab" & i.ToString)
      tbc.TabPages.Add(tbp)
      flp.Controls.Add(tbc)
    Next i
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please read the about statement that I cannot use the left alignment because of the way the text displays. That is why I am forced to go use draw.mode

Comment: I've added another possible solution, above

Comment: I haven't forgotten your solution, I have yet to try it out and report my findings. Also at the bottom of my question is "tab example" thats where the first code left me. Im ready to try anything at this point.